# jQuery: Retrieve the ID of a nested div element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI sortable to sort the list elements in my page. After sorting, I would like to get the ID's of the buttons. As of now, I am able to capture the `<div>` elements in the list. But, I would like to get the ID's the buttons which has the `class='buttonData'`. I have pasted sample HTML, CSS and jQuery code below for reference. Thanks.

```js
 $(".multipleButtons").sortable({
                connectWith: '.multipleButtons',
                stop: function (ev, ui) {
                    var hasLooped = false;
                    var list = $(ui.item).parent().find(".adminMenuButton").each(function (index) {
                        if (!hasLooped) {
                            console.log(ui.item[0]);
                            console.log(ui.item[0].nextElementSibling);
                            console.log(ui.item[0].previousElementSibling);
                            hasLooped = true;
                        }
                    })
                }
            }).disableSelection();
        }
```

```css
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">  
    .landingmenu > ul > fieldset {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

```html
 <div class="landingmenu">
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Groups[i].Id, new { @class = "adminMenuGroupId" })
      <div class="btn-group multipleButtons">
      @for (int x = 0; x < Model.Groups[i].Buttons.Count; x++)
      {
    <div class="landingmenu btn-group">
       <a href="@Model.Groups[i].Buttons[x].URL" target="@(Model.Groups[i].Buttons[x].OpensInNewWindow ? "_blank" : "_self" )" class="adminMenuButton buttonData btn btn-default talent-solid-btn buttonspace">@Model.Groups[i].Buttons[x].Name</a>
    @if (ViewBag.IsSiteAdmin)
    {
     <div id="grp-@Model.Groups[i].Id:btn-@Model.Groups[i].Buttons[x].Id" class="buttonData">
    </div>
      btnId++;
      }                                                    
    </div>
    }
   </div> 
</div>
```

Below is the `console.log` in my browser, highlighted is the ID's which I want to capture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided I understand, you have an outer div and some buttons within that div. You want a list of ids of those buttons.  I think this will fix you up:

```
<div id="outerdiv">
<div class="buttonData" id="test1">Test </div>
<div class="buttonData" id="test2">Test </div>
<div class="buttonData2" id="test3">Test</div>
<div class="buttonData" id="test4">Test</div>  
</div>
```

The javascript

```
var arr = [];
$("#outerdiv > div.buttonData").each(function(){
    arr.push(this.id);
   alert(this.id);
})
```

Here is a jsfiddle demo, too: https://jsfiddle.net/m1xorfw7/1/

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it does not working in my case.

Comment: This works.. added the id to the outerdiv correctly this time. Thanks